# best way to save value in variable to use after the application is closed and start again in android using apache cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cookies

Hello devs I am making my first android game using Apache cordova. 
I am stuck in making a highscore part. Please help me tell what is the best way to make it that it is stored even if the application is closed and opened again. 
I am thinking about using cookies but wondering if its valid to use it and what is the best practice. I am newbie in javascript and jquery so dont know much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easyest is to use the localstorage.

Write a value :

```
window.localStorage.setItem(paramName, paramValue);
```

Read a value :

```
value=window.localStorage.getItem(paramName);
```

You just have to remember that you store strings, not object. So if you need to store complex objects, first stringify it before you save to the local storage.